# how to design a tag system for a localized website?

Tags: localization, tags

Let say i have a basic tagging system  (for a craiglists "clone") such as:

Tag (id, tagname)
ad(id, title, body)
adTag(tag_id, article_id)

This will fit for a non-localized website but what will be the correct aproach for a website that is used by people speaking diferent languages?

Users probably will post ads in diferent languages in one same local area, so, maybe i should make some kind of synonym system that considers "job" and "trabajo" the same tag? But, what about users that only want to see ads in one language?

Answer (score 0):

Catering for tags for all the different languages is probably just going to be trouble. Going with the idea where you treat all variations of a tag as one single type will probably simplify a lot of the issues (so you don't need to keep track of language-tag mappings on the fly, just do the conversion once and be done with it). If the user needs to search by language later on, then just stick a meta-tag for that particular language on when you save the post.

Of course, that leaves the question of what happens when a user uses tags from multiple languages... but I suppose you can always enforce one single language or something.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two possible solutions:

1. Add language field: Tag (id, tagname, lang) where you can specify the language for the tag
2. Change Tag to Tag(id) and use separate table for tag translations tagTranslations(tag_id, lang, tagname)

Note: But I think this is only needed, if your articles have multiple translations.